# Jquery to select DIV by iterated ID

Tags: jquery

I would like to select each of these divs separately. Here is what I am trying:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="options_sort1"></div>
<div id="options_sort2"></div>
<div id="options_sort3"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
  var $div = $('[id ^=options_sort][id $=counter]');
}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat curious what this does. As it is, you're simply assigning the last of the 3 elements to `$div`, a variable that's unavailable outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    var div = $('#options_sort' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
  var $div = $('#options_sort' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
 var div = $('#options_sort'+i);
}
```

Don't forget to remove $ of "$div" and add jQuery to your code;